# How do I read setRequestHeader OF XMLHttpRequest to my API?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, fastapi

I have a program - chrome extension - sending API calls to an API I have hosted on Heroku - FastAPI, Python. I used setRequestHeader() containing unique user ID with XML API call and want to read the header from my API - so I can limit the calls for each unique userid header e.g to 1 a second.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", checkDomain, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + userid);
(req.send(null);
```

Then js code later to read response which is always empty from API endpoint which returns the Header of user

FastAPI side code -

```
 #Reads header?
 @app.get("/items/")
 async def read_items(user_agent: Optional[str] = Header(None)):
     return {"User-Agent": Header}
```

Returned value which I parse and alert from chrome extension side is always {"User-Agent":""} empty object but goes through successfully

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way!

You can find everything about the request inside `Request` object.

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(request: Request):
    return request.headers
```

This contains everything about the request headers, if you only want to get user agent you can simply do this

```py
return request.headers['user-agent']
```